# Doctrine DQL - Expected end of string, got 'inner'

Tags: mysql, symfony, join, doctrine-orm, dql

I'm trying to perform kinda simple query, but I always get this exception

> [Syntax Error] line 0, col 157: Error: Expected end of string, got
>   'inner'

Here's my query:

```
public function hasRecord($user, $event)
{
    $q = $this->getEntityManager()->createQuery("
                select count(h.id) from Tsk\FEBundle\Entity\History h
                inner join h.user u where u.id = :user
                inner join h.event v and v.id = :event
            ");

    $q->setParameters([
        "user" => $user,
        "event" => $event
    ]);
    return $q->getSingleScalarResult();
}
```

How can I perform two inner joins ? Is there something wrong with my query ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should do your joins before `where` clause:

```
public function hasRecord($user, $event)
{
    $q = $this->getEntityManager()->createQuery("
                select count(h.id) from Tsk\FEBundle\Entity\History h
                inner join h.user u
                inner join h.event v
                where u.id = :user
                and v.id = :event
            ");

    $q->setParameters([
        "user" => $user,
        "event" => $event
    ]);
    return $q->getSingleScalarResult();
}
```